# What approach would an algo trader use if the previously stable spread on ETF ABC widens against ETF XYZ from ABC becoming more valuable versus XYZ?

Tags: trading

This is an quiz question in linkedin's algo trading class.

Question:
What approach would an algo trader use if the previously stable spread on ETF ABC widens against ETF XYZ from ABC becoming more valuable versus XYZ?

The answer is

```
Go Long ABC and Short XYZ
```

And the explanation is
Yes, the algo trader would bet on the spread reconverging.

I have a hard time understanding the question. What's spread in this case? The bid-ask spread? If abc is becoming more valuable, which should I short abc if it's going to go back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

"spread" in this context is just the difference between the two ETFs (not B/A spread). Typically it's used to measure against some benchmark, but it can be used against two arbitrary instruments.

However, the answer seems backwards to the question. If one expects the spread between ABC and XYZ to close (meaning that ABC - XYZ gets smaller) then one would go ***SHORT*** ABC and ***LONG*** XYZ, not the other way around.

The answer *does* make sense if ABC trades for *less* than XYZ, in which case the "spread" is negative and you'd make the trades outlined in the answer (since ABC would gain relative to XYZ), but that detail is left out of the question as posted.

Comment: What to short is dependent on over/undervalue not price (consider VOO at at $279 and SPY at $304).  Whether the spread is negative or positive is also irrelevant. ABC-XYZ results in  the same graph as XYZ-ABC only the direction of the change in value is different.   It's the expansion or contraction of the spread that is the objective.  Another consideration  can be ratioing ABC versus XYZ to achieve a 1:1 dollar correlation.

Comment: @BobBaerker Suppose VOO is consistently $25 below SPY (a "stable spread" as per the scenario), but at some point SPY rises to $310 while VOO only rises to $281 (the spread widens to $29). Which one if over/under valued? Maybe _both_ are overvalued but the scenario is that an algo trader expecting the _spread_ to retract back to normal would short SPY and buy VOO. So it _is_ about price when you're talking spreads. I agree that in the real world the _relative_ spread may be more constant but that's not the scenario that's lined out.

Comment: Your example  lacks the appropriate information to answer. Be that as it may, ABC and XYZ being over/undervalued as compared to underlying index is irrelevant. The pair is put on because one is overvalued as compared to the other, not to the underlying. A simple example with extreme numbers for ease of illustration. ABC is $50 and XYZ is $100.  Both are SPX ETFs and they are properly valued.  The next day, ABC is $55 and XYZ is $110 (both rose 10%). If you just looked at price (the spread widened $5), you'd be misled into believing that at $55/$110 it's a viable pair. It's not

Comment: What's problematic in the above example is that if you put on the pair at $50/$100, a 10% move in the wrong direction loses money, yet the pct change was the same.  That's why the positions need ratioing.  As for under/over value, graphing either the difference in price or the quotient of price (Comparative Relative Strength) will depict the pair's over/undervalue relationship. It's more than I want to explain so I'll just state that if you tie the pair of the same underlying  to yield, it clarifies the  under/over value.

Comment: @BobBaerker Again, I'm using the "previously stable spread" assumption in the question to mean a stable _absolute_ spread, not relative, but the answer would be the same in either case. If the _relative_ spread widens, you'd make the same trade.

Comment: Your answer is as nebulous as the OP's question, especially the part about a 'negative spread'. And wWhat you are stating in your comments is not apparent in the answer.  Just curious, have you ever done pairs trading?

Comment: I'm an analyst, not a trader, which is probably why my answers tend to come more from the analytical/theoretical side than the practical/real-world side.

Answer (score 0):

I have an issue with the Algo answer but before I get to that, if the B/A spread widens, you have more to overcome just to break even on a position.  In addition, you can't profitably pairs trade based on the B/A spread width because there's no meat there.

I have no idea what the lingo of the Algo class is so here's my take from having  profitably traded an awful lot of pairs in every major volatile time period since 2008. You sell the overvalued security and you buy the undervalued security.

Something doesn't add up here (the question and their answer)  so I'll leave it to you to figure out exactly what the Algo class is suggesting. Based on the wording of your question, I would buy XYZ because it's undervalued and short ABC because it's overvalued.

Here's an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20171106004248/http://www.investopedia.com/university/guide-pairs-trading/pairs-trade-example.asp) about pairs.